# Apache error when loading a file using jquery load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, load

The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
getting the above error when trying to load a jsp file using jquery load function()

```
$(".RelServ_left").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".RelServ_slider").animate({width:'360px'});
    $(".RelServ_slider").load("web2/pages/module/jsdn/store/relatedInfo.jsp");
});
```

any error in the way iam calling the the function?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `full path` of your `jsp page` like,

```
$(".RelServ_slider").load("http://example.com/web2/pages/module/jsdn/store/relatedInfo.jsp");
```

Comment: @sp2358234 then check your `url` is working in `browser` by hitting it directly in browser, also confirm that you have no settings in `htaccess`.

Comment: i have no settings in htaccess

Comment: Got the ans, should have inserted the attribute in the particular action